# OpenCV android- App crashes when I click the bottun, don't know why

Tags: android, opencv, histogram

I'm quite new to programming on android.
Currently I'm trying to make a histogram comparison application using Androidstudio and OpenCV. Unfortunately,  I don't know why my app gets closed when I click my onclick function. Here's the code if anyone could help me, I'd be very thankful. I've been googling for a while and couldn't find the answer

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.Slika);
    image2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.Slika2);
    image1.setClickable(true);
    image2.setClickable(true);
    botun = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.botun);
    startaj();
}


    public void startaj(){

    image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            imgNo = 2;

        }
    } );

        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
                imgNo = 1;

            }
        });

        botun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Određivanje broj kvantizacija
                int huebins=50;
                int satbins=60;

                MatOfInt HistKvant=new MatOfInt(huebins,satbins);
                //Hue razine između 0-179, saturation 0-255
                MatOfFloat histogramrange=new MatOfFloat(0f,180f,0f,256f);

                //Vrijednost histograma spremamo u ovo matricu
                Mat HistValue1=new Mat();
                Mat HistValue2=new Mat();

                //Broj kanala hue/sat
                MatOfInt mChannels=new MatOfInt(0,1);

                //Reduciranje bitmapa da je lakše računanje ( dimenzija )
                bitmap1red=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1,200,200,true);
                bitmap2red=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2,200,200,true);


                //transformacija slika iz Bitmap formata u Mat -> HSV sliku
                Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1red,Histoslika1);
                Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap2red,Histoslika2);

                Imgproc.cvtColor(Histoslika1,Histoslika1,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(Histoslika2,Histoslika2,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

                Histoslika1.convertTo(Histoslika1, CvType.CV_32F);
                Histoslika2.convertTo(Histoslika2, CvType.CV_32F);


                ArrayList<Mat> histImage1=new ArrayList<Mat>();
                histImage1.add(Histoslika1);

                ArrayList<Mat> histImage2=new ArrayList<Mat>();
                histImage1.add(Histoslika2);


                //računanje Histograma
                Imgproc.calcHist(histImage1, mChannels, new Mat(), HistValue1, HistKvant, histogramrange);
                Core.normalize(HistValue1, HistValue1, 0, HistValue1.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
                Imgproc.calcHist(histImage2, mChannels, new Mat(), HistValue2, HistKvant, histogramrange);
                Core.normalize(HistValue2, HistValue2, 0, HistValue2.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

                double Compareresults=Imgproc.compareHist(HistValue1,HistValue2,Imgproc.CV_COMP_CHISQR);
                double bestresults=0;
                if(Compareresults>bestresults){bestresults=Compareresults;}

                //Slanje rezultata u activity_results;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, results.class);
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putDouble("bestresults",bestresults);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


    }
```

Logcat :

> 07-13 15:24:55.236 19457-19457/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   07-13 15:24:55.434 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.615 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.661 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.707 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.764 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.814 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.875 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.917 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.959 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:55.999 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:56.045 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.kresimir.imagedetect-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
>   07-13 15:24:56.054 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
>   07-13 15:24:56.125 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
>   07-13 15:24:56.154 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>   07-13 15:24:56.320 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
>   07-13 15:24:56.399 19457-19531/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   07-13 15:24:56.452 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
>   07-13 15:24:56.658 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect E/art: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
>   07-13 15:24:56.678 19457-19457/com.example.kresimir.imagedetect I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19457 SIG: 9

Comment: If you are coding on Android Studio whenever there is an app crash the error gets printed in the logcat. It would really help if you could paste the error along with your answer.

Comment: share the error logs

Comment: updated, but seems too long?